# Tkinter global keys with pynput not working

Tags: python, tkinter, keyboard, pynput

As suggested, I'm using pynput keyboard for call a function globally using shortcut key, but tkinter won't start anymore. what am I doing wrong? thank you!

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
from pynput import keyboard

def call_me(event=""):
    messagebox.showinfo("trying","thisa")
    

root = tk.Tk()


button = tk.Button(root, text="call me", command = call_me)


button.pack()

root.geometry("300x300")

with keyboard.GlobalHotKeys({
        '<ctrl>+<alt>+h': call_me}) as h:
        h.join()


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Fyi, **GlobalHotKeys** is a threading.Thread. Your tkinter won't run because GlobalHotKeys calls **h.join()**, which starts a *blocking thread* that blocks the main thread of the program and only terminates when the GlobalHotKeys thread ends (which in your case never does). Thus, your program will run continually without tkinter calling mainloop().

```
with keyboard.GlobalHotKeys({
        '<ctrl>+<alt>+h': call_me}) as h:
        h.join()

root.mainloop()
```

To remedy this, start the GlobalHotKeys thread in a *non-blocking fashion*.

```
hotkeys = keyboard.GlobalHotKeys({
    '<ctrl>+<alt>+h': call_me})

hotkeys.start()
root.mainloop()
```

The GlobalHotKeys thread will run concurrently as a daemon thread with the tkinter event loop -- root.mainloop() -- in the main thread, which should fix your problem! The daemon thread process will automatically end once you quit the main thread.

Click [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) for more on Python threads and [here](https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html) for pynput.keyboard